# "Navigation Bar" SWT control

Tags: swt

Does already someone has written an SWT control like the "Navigation Bar" in IDEA? For those who don't know what I mean: it looks like

```
path1 > path2 > path3 >
```

where each "path" is a part of a full path simulating a button which can be clicked and shows a popup, e.g. to easily switch to a different parallel directory of the currently opened file.

Comment: Have you checked http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtbreadcrumb/ and http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Breadcrumb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the following links:

1. [swtbreadcrumb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swtbreadcrumb/) and
2. [Breadcrumb](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Breadcrumb)